# Adding leading zeros to a string on Linux

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk

I have a file containing a list of names. I need to make name length to 11 characters. Is there any single line command to do the job?

Example:

#### file1.txt

```
ABCDE001
ABCDE002
```

Expected:

#### file1.txt

```
000ABCDE001
000ABCDE002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%0"  11-length($0) "d%s\n", 0, $0}' file
000ABCDE001
000ABCDE002
```

Comment: It is working fine!. Thanks. Can you pls explain how it actually works?

Comment: Yes sure. `11-length($0)` subtracts length of input from 11. The difference is then used in `printf` format like this: `printf "%03d%s\n"`. Here 3 is difference and `%03d` is used for left padding with zeroes.

Answer (score 5):

The following Perl one-liner could help you:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\S+)/("0" x (11 - length $1)) . $1/eg' file.txt
```

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Perl one-liner,

```
perl -pe 's|(\w+)| sprintf("%011s", $1) |e' file1.txt
```

Add the `-i` switch to apply changes to the file.